# Match Dates with Time Periods

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have transaction data which includes a trade date. I want to be able to match the trade date of the transaction with the matching time period.

I have a table with 5 different time periods like so:

Period 1: 1/1/2000 - 3/31/2000

Period 2: 4/4/2001 - 6/6/2001

Period 3: 10/10/2002 - 12/31/2002

etc.

I want to be able to match the dates from the transaction data with their matching period for further calculation purposes.

The only solution I could thing of was nested if formulas but those are always ugly and depending on how many different periods I have not usable.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Public Sub RangeChecker()
Dim date1, date2, myDate As Date
Dim myDateStatus As String

date1 = CDate("January 1, 2000")
date2 = CDate("June 1, 2000")
myDate = CDate("May 1, 2000")

If (myDate > date1 And myDate < date2) Then

myDateStatus = "The date is inside the range"
Else
myDateStatus = "The date is outside the range"
End If
MsgBox (myDateStatus)

End Sub
```

You should only need one if statement per date range.

Comment: Interesting havent thought about a macro approach will test this out.

Comment: Let me know if you need any more input. I now realize this might be overkill for what you're doing though...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer when you don't specify enough the layout of your data, which thing is in which column etc. Supposing the periods are defined in columns A, B and C, and the date for which you want to find the period is `F2`, you can use this *CSE formula*:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$7<=F2)*(F2<=$C$2:$C$7),0))
' enter then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

[image]

Comment: You are right but looking at it this looks pretty similar to my setup. I will test this tomorrow and let you know! Thanks for the help!